# Netlogo : invalid context

Tags: netlogo

My first netlogo program was working well, but now is failing since 'tick' in the 'go' method is not in a valid context.

Please see the attached code, line 99, which generates:
You can't use tick in a turtle/patch context, because it is observer only.

Code is here:
http://jpark.us/temp/CSSS.v1.nlogo

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved...

I was trying to 'set number.sparrows...' down in other methods, but not within a proper patches context.

So this works:

```
if all? patches [ eggs.laid = true ] [ 
  ask patches [ set number.sparrows count sparrows-here ]
```

whereas this does not:

```
if all? patches [ eggs.laid = true ] [ 
  set number.sparrows count sparrows-here
```

Comment: well done for solving it yourself. You said that this is your first model. As a general rule, the invalid context error is because you forgot to close a bracket somewhere.